# Optimizing ListAdapter by checking if the ViewHolder is using the same model object

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to know it is a good optimization to check if the `ViewHolder` is using the same model object. This is for cases when it is expensive to populate the `View` returned by `getView()`.

This assumes that the view content does not change - which I think is the common case.

For example, the standard pattern is:

```java
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Model model = models.get(position);
    if (convertView != null) {
                    // View was recycled. Get the holder.
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
                    // Inflate a new layout and create a holder
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // Fill in the content
    Bitmap imgBitmap = loadBitmapFor(model.getName());

    if (imgBitmap != null) {
        viewHolder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        viewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
            }

    viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    ImageView img;
}
```

We optimize by checking if the `ListView` is looking at the same object at the same position:

```java
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Model model = models.get(position);

            boolean recycled;
    if (convertView != null) {
                    // View was recycled. Get the holder.
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    recycled = true;
    } else {
                    // Inflate a new layout and create a holder
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.model = model;
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                    recycled = false;
    }

            // Skip the expensive content loading if we can
            if (recycled && (model == viewHolder.model) && (position == viewHolder.position)) {
                return convertView;
            }

    // Fill in the content
    Bitmap imgBitmap = loadBitmapFor(model.getName());

    if (imgBitmap != null) {
        viewHolder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        viewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
            }

    viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
            int position; // for double checking_
            Model model;
    TextView name;
    ImageView img;                
}
```

Comment: Will the new position ever equal the view-holder's previous position?

Comment: Yes, the positions do become equal. I see it by logging. It doesn't seem to occur often, but since the Bitmap creation is expensive I think it may be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since view recycling works mainly like this: http://android.amberfog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/listview_recycler.jpg

It is unlikely that the new position and previous position of the recycled view are the same.

You should focus on **caching** the `Bitmap`s instead. Generate the `Bitmap`s on demand and then place them in the cache. You can use an `LruCache` (which is available in the compatibility library) as shown here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: This is correct. My code above has a bug - viewHolder.position == position will always be true. The wrong content will be recycled.

I decided to use `LruCache`. Instead of caching the decompressed Bitmap, I cached the file data to save memory.